# Path issue implementing an application inside an Asp.net Webforms Site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

We have a web site running on IIS7.5 using ASP.NET web forms. All the website paths are in the format: `"~/"`.

Inside this website we have an application that loads one page of the parent website inside an `<iframe>` tag.

Obviously all the reference paths in the `<iframe>` content are referred (and point to) the application root and not at the website root.

Is there a way to point the `<iframe>` content to the website root only changing the application or at least the website `web.config`, but not making mods on the website code?

Comment: Much better match for StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you show us your folder structure so we can visualise this better?